# Cannot build dependencies for banshee

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, build-dependencies, banshee

I'd like to do some `banshee` development, so I went here http://banshee.fm/download/development/ and tried to follow steps ...

I am using `ubuntu 14.04`, and I got the following error ..

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep banshee
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Failed to satisfy Build-Depends dependency for banshee: Installed package libgpod-cil-dev is too new
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but I found this solution

**Use this instead of apt-get:** `sudo aptitude build-dep banshee`

Source https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1335614